# Cant type anything in HTML textbox

Tags: html

so Im trying to create a textbox (named SearchUp) where I can search for names. However it is not allowing me to type anything in it which is weird because all of my other text boxes work. I was hoping someone would be able to help me out with this. Thanks.

Here is the HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" style="background-color:#99ebff;">


  <head >
    <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie|Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700italic|Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src= "js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
    <script src= "js/jquery.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="myapp2" ng-controller= "MainController">
    <header>


    <nav class = "main-navigation" role='navigation'>
      <ul>
        <li style= "font-size: 20px;">Name</li>
        <input type = "text" name = "Name" size = "40" class = "box1" ng-model = "input"/>

        <li style= "font-size: 20px;">Number</li>
        <input type = "text" name = "Number" size = "40" class = "box2" ng-model = "input2"/>

        <li style= "font-size: 20px;">Appointment Date</li>
        <input type = "text" name = "Date" size = "40" class = "box3" ng-model = "input3" />

        <li ><a href = '#' style = "text-decoration: none; color: inherit;" class = "button" ng-click = "addName()" >Submit</a>
          <a href = '#' style = "text-decoration: none; color: inherit;" class = "cancel">Cancel</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- <li class = "cancel"><a href = '#' style = "text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">Cancel</a></li> -->
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
  <div class="header" >
    <!-- ng-app = "instantSearch" ng-controller = "InstantSearchController" -->

    <div class = "card">
        <div class = "front">
            <h1><span >Appointments</span></h1>

        </div>
        <div class = "back">
            <a href = "#" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;"><h1><span>Add patient</span></h1></a>
        </div>
    </div>
      <a href = "" class = "search" style = "text-decoration: none; color: white;"> Search </a>
</div> 
<nav class= "side-navigation" role='navigation' >

  <input type = "text" name = "SearchUp" size = "40" class = "box1" />

  <div ng-repeat=" patient in patients | filter: searchKeyword" >
        <!-- | searchFor:searchString -->

        <div class="item col-md-12 " >
           <h3 class="name2" style ="padding-top: 40px;"><a href = "" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">{{patient.name}}</a> </h3>

        </div>



      </div>
    </nav>

  <div class="main" >

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f2f2f2">


      <h2 class = "item col-md-4">Patients</h2>
      <h2 class = "item col-md-4">Phone Number</h2>
      <h2 class = "item col-md-4">Appointment Date</h2>
      <div ng-repeat=" patient in patients" >
        <div class = "patientz" style = "display: inline;">


        <div class="item col-md-4 " >
           <h3 class="name"><a href = "#" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">{{patient.name}}</a> </h3>

        </div>
        <div class="price col-md-4">
          <p class="price">{{patient.number}} </p>
        </div>
        <div class="price col-md-4" >
          <p class="date" > {{ patient.date}} 
              <a href = "" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" class = "reminder"> send reminder</a>
         </p>

        </div>


      </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
  </div>

</body>

</html> 


    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="/Users/singh/Desktop/front-end twilio/js/app.js"></script>


    <!--Controllers -->
    <script src="/Users/singh/Desktop/front-end twilio/js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
```

Comment: The code you have posted does not represent your problem. You can easily type in that input textbox ("SearchUp").

Comment: When writing your [MCVE]: *Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem*

Comment: How are we supposed to figure out what effect `<script src="/Users/singh/Desktop/front-end twilio/js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>` might have on your problem? Create a proper [MCVE], not a dump of a big stack of code which may or may not be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Been trying to. For some reason I have to scroll the page down a little to be able to type into it. I think i'll manage, thanks.

Comment: Fixed it. I just had to move the textbox down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP states above:

> I just had to move the textbox down.